# Import .class file in android java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

is there any other way to import another Java class from the same package in android?

I'm trying to import store.class to SMSreceiver.class
in SMSreceiver.class, i type in this code, store storingKey = new store();

but still cannot call the methods in store.class

this will be my store.class coding.

```
public class store extends Activity{
    public store(){

    }

     public void saveToFile(String filename, String sms) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException{
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND));
            out.write(sms);
            out.close();            
    }
```

is there any problem with my coding?

any help?

Rob, this is my another class

```
public class storePubKey extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    Activity ac = new Activity();
    store sk = new store();
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        try{
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, "f", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sk.saveToFile("public.key", str);
            Toast.makeText(context,("public.keyasd"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        }catch(Exception e){}

        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        try {
            //Toast.makeText(context,str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try this

To call a non-static method in another class, you need a reference to that class.

```
store storeRef = new store(); // create new instance and set reference
storeRef.saveToFile(); // call the method
```

If you already have a reference to that class, you don't need to create it. A reference can be passed in a method call:

```
public void calledMethod(store storeRef) {
storeRef.saveToFile();
```

***UPDATE***

Change
*storeKey sk = new storeKey();*
 to
***store sk = new store();***

Since store is your original class name, not storeKey.

You also may need to declare that withing the method you are trying to use it in.

Comment: yes, i'd already did that. But still the same. i cannot call the saveToFile method..

Comment: can you paste the code from your other class?  I will then edit my answer with how it should work.

Comment: sorry Rob, there's a typo, its store, not storeKey. Sorry, there's still an error

Comment: Is the error a force close or is it before compiling?  If so what is the error?

Comment: after i called this method, if this method can run, Toast will show the string "public.keyasd" right?
sk.saveToFile("public.key", str);
            Toast.makeText(context,("public.keyasd"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

but it never show...thats the problem

Comment: if you move store sk = new store(); to the onReceive method does it change anything?

Comment: this time i get force close error...:(
i really need help, as this is my final year project..

Comment: hmm..i had change the code, and it gets the same result as after i called this method, if this method can run, Toast will show the string "public.keyasd" right? sk.saveToFile("public.key", str); Toast.makeText(context,("public.keyasd"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); but it never show... this

Comment: Set the code back to the point where it will run, and then paste the error that is being displayed in eclipse please

Comment: GC_EXPLICIT freed 31k, 55% free 2681K/5831K external 716K/1038K, paused 99ms

Comment: skipping unknown process PID 1990,1991

Comment: the last one is request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: Im lost, i really apologize.. not sure where else to go from here as I am nearly a beginner as well.